# joomla front page not upload after change hosting

Tags: joomla2.5, php-5.3

I facing a problem please help me.
I have changed my hosting & uploaded joomla 2.5 webiste to our new host, but front page not loaded & administrator working very fine. I have uploaded many times but still it is not working.There is no errors showing on the site. i am very confused how to solve this problem.
i request to all please solve my problem.

My domain is http://indiataxionline.in/
working Domain http://indiataxionline.com/

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is the new domain name and related information in the DNS has not refreshed. As a rule, it may take **24-48 hours**.

**Ping command** in the console does not find the node that confirms this.

It is also possible in the site settings are incorrect **NS records.**